# Configure AX endpoint in Scribe insight

Tags: integration, axapta, endpoint

I'm configuring the adapter for AX, all the steps in the configuration have been performed.

In the inbound ports I found this one: http://servername/MicrosoftDynamicsAxAif60/ScribeAxWebService/xppservice.svc but I get this error:

```
Connection Error: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client
authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header 
received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'.
```

If I go in AX and change the security mode to "None" for using anonymous authentication then I get

```
The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
The remote server returned an error: (415) 
Cannot process the message because the content type 
'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the 
expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..
```

Where can I find the right one?

Comment: It doesn't prompt you to login?  Are you just using a web browser to connect or some dev tools (vstudio or something)?

Comment: I have to provide user and passwords, since they are required in the configuration window

Answer (score 0):

Your question is for propriety software, so this isn't exactly the right forum for it, but I've used some older versions of Scribe (4+ yrs ago).

I'd guess the domain user account running the Scribe service is not added as an AX user.  Where are you getting "unauthorized"?

Comment: The domain user account that I use is an AX user

Answer (score 0):

You already have indicated that web.config is changed, but there is a good example on MSDN, see the section [XML Snippet from Web.Config](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc652581(v=ax.50).aspx).  There are TWO changes to be made.  The `wsHttpBinding` section, and then to each service that it's `binding = "wsHttpBinding"` is correct.

Finally, I also [add a log file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc967372(v=ax.50).aspx) to AIF during the testing phase.